# Javascript get all content of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using **Jquery FullCalendar** When i click to button i want to export div content to excell.

I am trying to get **calendar's div content** on click to button.

**Html:**

```
<script src="~/js/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>


<button onclick="tableToExcel()" type="button">Export To Excell</button>

<div class="calendar" name="calendar" id="calendar">
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function tableToExcel() {

    var calendar = document.getElementById("calendar").data;

    alert(calendar);

    window.location.href = "/Calendar/ExportData?calendar=" + calendar;
}
```

if i try  document.getElementById("calendar").data or document.getElementById("calendar").text alert displays

```
undefined
```

if i try document.getElementById("calendar").**innerHTML**

```
no data displaying inside of table
```

where i miss how can i get div content in a div by js ?

Comment: Try [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) or [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent).

Comment: it only displays html not data

Comment: what is expected result? If you want the event data use the API to access that. Not clear what goals are here

Comment: `innerHTML` gives you all the content within a div (tags and text content) as a string. If that doesn't contain the data you need, it's stored elsewhere.

Comment: innerHtml displays html(class etc.) textContent displays(data) i need both of them at the same time

Comment: If you need both of them then create two variables, one for each and alert the concatenation of the two. You could simplify the problem if you added JQuery to your project.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery

```
<button id="calendarBtn" type="button">Export To Excell</button>

$('#calendarBtn').on("click", function () {
    var calendar = $('#calendar').attr("name");
    console.log( calendar );
    window.location.href = "/Calendar/ExportData?calendar=" + calendar;
});
```

Comment: is it finished because i tried this and no solution

Comment: if you want to get the whole div's html, try: var calendar = $('#calendar').get(0);

Comment: the attr("name") function will return the name attribute in the selected div.